# PHP CURL => Rest API (GET) = HTTP_CODE 401

Tags: php, rest, curl, nginx

The following script returns "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized" by requesting, but i am not sure why. I know, the request goes to a https, but i "denied" the option "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER".. and i think, that's not the problem at all, is it?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$html_brand = "https://example.com/api/test";
$ch = curl_init();

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $html_brand,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH       => CURLAUTH_DIGEST,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD        => "user:pass",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'
        )
);
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $httpCode != 200 ){
    echo "Return code is {$httpCode} \n"
        .curl_error($ch);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
} else {
    echo "<pre>".htmlspecialchars($response)."</pre>";
}

curl_close($ch);
```

I think, there is just one more option for the curl missing..

Response:

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>   Server: nginx
>   Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 18:52:26 GMT
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Keep-Alive: timeout=5
>   Www-Authenticate: Digest realm="REST-API", domain="/", nonce="", opaque="", algorithm="MD5", qop="auth"
>   Cache-Control: nocache, private
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding
>
> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   Server: nginx
>   Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 18:52:26 GMT
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Keep-Alive: timeout=5
>   Cache-Control: nocache, private
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding

May it's kind of stupid, but is it something about the auth algorithm - md5? The password is in plain-text and not encrypted by md5.

EDIT: It seems, that it's not about MD5 - got same response after coding password to md5.

ONE MORE Edit: Okay, same client works pretty well on HTTP Layer (and another INSTANCE!) instead HTTPS.. So something is broken on HTTPS?

Comment: Are you sure the target API requires HTTP Digest authentication instead of Basic? Just try and remove the `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH       => CURLAUTH_DIGEST,` from the array and see what happens.

Comment: Hi @HansZ. thank you, but yes, i tried.. Nothing changed so far :/

Comment: Are you sure you're putting in the right username/password in the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option?

Comment: I am. I also can request the same API over HTTP in my browser. That was the first thing i checked. The credentials are valid

Comment: If it works in your browser, then see what is the request that your browser sends and try to make the same request with cURL.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case server had a 301 redirect to url with double slash. In browser's address bar it was invisble, when I checked server response to my browser I realized that.